# Using Customer Session Factory to avoid depersonalization

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish, customer-session

We have a plugin that adjusts the customer price on the frontend based on its customer ID. When you use the the Customer Session class it is depersonzalized for a very good reason. But when you use the factory of the same class sudenly you have all the customer data you need. My questions for using this method :

- Does this create multiple caching instances for the same page when FPC enabled
- Does this have certain security risks?
- When using this is there any chance of caching the customer data resulting in mixed results?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22751

Comment: Bumping to find an answer, like all other issues they have come to the stackexchange to die...

Without any actual evidence, I imagine there is some sort of data initialisation built into the session factory's `create` method that is not called when you inject the session into a class. It seems like it is intended functionality and if you need a depersonalized customer session you should forego using the factory and inject it directly, but that's just me spitballing here :)